# How to measure current to detect motor stall on H-Bridge driven motor?

Tags: dc-motor, current-measurement, h-bridge

I have DC motor with a gearbox to transforms the rotational movement to linear movement and movie a pin back and forward.

I need to know when the pin reaches the two positions: full back or full forward.

The motor is a simple DC brushed one (3V low speed, the current on free movement is around 11.8mA) and it will be driven by an ESP8266 through an H-Bridge.

There're no sensors to detect pin position (and nonot enough space to add them), so my idea is to measure the motor current and when I read a fast increment it means the pin is full forward/backward (motor close to stall).

How can I measure the current and read by a microcontroller to drive the motor via H-bridge?

Answer (score 4):

Put your current sensor in one of the supply lines that feeds the H-bridge. Either put a high-side sensor in series with the positive supply, or put a low-side sensor in series with its ground connection. Regardless of which way the motor is turning, the current flows through these points in only one direction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGMBJa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The advantage of low-side sensing is that your feedback signal is automatically ground-referenced. But you can get ICs from several vendors that make high-side sensing just as easy.

I've shown resistors, but you could instead use a Hall-effect sensor in either position and also get a ground-referenced output.